# Is PhoneGap 2.5 syntax changed?

Tags: cordova

I am a newbie of PhoneGap. I setup a new PhoneGap project and looked at the default generated functions. They has the structure as this :

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
        //do something
    }
```

Every PhoneGap sample which I saw, has below syntax :

```
 function onDeviceReady() {       
        //do something
    }
```

I declare my functions at what I see on PhoneGap sample and it doesn't work. Is it deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

the samples u saw will have code like function onDeviceReady() {
        //do something
    }

There is no colon between function and device ready. So both should work.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct javascript syntax and used depending on how you declare the object.

Using object literal notation, you will see something like this:

```
app = {
   onDeviceReady: function(){ }  
}
```

while using the "normal" way is like this:

```
function onDeviceReady(){

}

app.onDeviceReady = onDeviceReady
```